# BLE Android scanRecord all zeroes

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop a BLE application on Android (API 19) that would read data from Waspmote sensors. The data is sent in advertisements. My device (Nexus 5 with Android 4.4) detects the sensors (address and rssi), but the scanRecord array is always set to zeroes and I can't get the advertisement data. Also, scanRecord.length always returns 62.

I'm working with [this](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1553/bluetooth_smart_le_android_tutorial) example.

The Waspmote I'm using is a 1.2 version (and API 16) with a [BLE board](http://www.libelium.com/bluetooth-low-energy-ble-4-0-smart-connect-sensors-smartphone/) attached. I'm testing it without any sensor boards, so basically it works just as a constant BLE advertiser right now, there's no other functions. I have checked that another Waspmote board is able to get the advertisement data and view it.

The part of the Waspmote code responsible for this is here:

```
  uint8_t data[31];
  //data assignment
  aux = BLE.setAdvData(BLE_GAP_ADVERTISEMENT, data, 31);
  aux = BLE.setDiscoverableMode(BLE_GAP_USER_DATA);
```

Edit:
I have solved the issue. Waspmote does not format the data in the advertisement according to the standard; it has to be formatted by the programmer.

Comment: You might want to be more specific about what hardware your Waspmote sensor contains and what software it is running.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, thanks, I've added that information.